# How to find which repos a repo depends on at Github?

Tags: github, dependencies, repository

I want to find out which repos a repo depends on at Github.

Now I can only find the dependent repos of a repo, that is, which repos depends on a repo.

Can I find the repos in the reversed way at Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your notion of "dependencies".

In term of Git repositories, one clear dependency is the notion of **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**

On GitHub, simply check for the presence of a .gitmodules file, you you would get in it the list of the url of dependent repository.

But the reverse wouldn't be easy to get: for a given repo, is is harder to find the list of repositories using it.
Maybe try a [GitHub code search](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/), limiting its search to files with extension `.gitmodules`.
Example: [`vysheng/tg extension:gitmodules`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=vysheng%2Ftg%20extension%3Agitmodules&type=Code): you see the list of repos using `vysheng/tg` as a submodule that way.

Comment: Thanks, it answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

Since May 23rd, 2019 (two years later), you now have "[**Dependent repositories**](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-23-dependent-repositories/)"

> Dependent repositories surface data from the GitHub dependency graph, showcasing which public repositories depend on the packages in that repository.

See more at "[Listing the projects that depend on a repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-projects-that-depend-on-a-repository)"

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/graphs/dependents_graph.png]

Comment: What's the difference between "Packages" "Repositories" and "Applications"?

Comment: @endolith From "https://help.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/listing-the-projects-that-depend-on-a-repository": "Packages are repositories that contain a library in a package manager, whereas applications are repositories that depend on the selected repository. "

Comment: Is this feature available through GitHub REST API or GraphQL?

Comment: @TajkiaRahmanToma Maybe: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#dependencygraphdependency and https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/schema-previews#access-to-a-repositories-dependency-graph-preview, from https://github.community/t/github-dependency-graph-api/508/4: might not be fully supported yet.