# How to search only through _dependent_ repositories of a given repo on GitHub

Tags: github, dependencies, github-api

[GitHub started listing dependencies and dependents in mid-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279806/4341322). For libraries ([PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/network/dependents) in my case), there are too many to keep an overview of what functionality those dependents implement with that library. Unfortunately, there's no(t yet an) related option in their [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced).

I tried naively searching for ["from github import GitHub"](https://github.com/search?q=%22from+github+import+GitHub%22&type=Code) because that's what the library specifies as an example usage. However, this won't find codes that use more specialised imports.

What's an elegant way to search through *dependent* repositories of a given repo on GitHub? Is there any tool that can do it already, or do I need to [construct such a search against their API](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/dependencygraphmanifestconnection/)?

Comment: There is an [open feedback discussion](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/5575), hopefully it'll land on the roadmap soon™️